# Reading from a multi-level JSON using getJSON into Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization, getjson

Quicker rundown (more detailed below): Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4815162342/xhp3g7u9/). The commented out part in the middle is what needs work. I can't get the json data added to the table. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

I'm trying to add some basic data into a Table in Google Charts. I've found that it's easy to read from one level of a JSON, but once you get into multiple levels, I can't figure out how to make it work. Basically, I want to add a row in the table for each Date/Name/Users grouping. Here's what I have so far (the $.getJSON part in the middle is the important part):

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
          var array = [['Date', 'Country', 'Users']];
          var sample = [new Date(2014, 6, 5), 'USA', 12];
          array.push(sample);



          $.getJSON('/JSON/Index', { get_param: 'value' }, function (data) {
              $.each(data.UsersByDateList, function (key, value) {
                  $.each(value.UsersByDate, function (key2, value2) {
                      var item = [new value2.Date, value.Name, value2.Users];
                      array.push(item);
                  });
              });
          });



          sample = [new Date(2014, 6, 19), 'USA', 12];
          array.push(sample);

          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
          var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
          table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
      }
   </script>
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "NumRecords": "5123",
   "UsersByDateList": [
      {
         "Name": "Steve",
         "UsersByDate": [
            {
               "Date": "Date(2014,5,1)",
               "Users": 54
            },
            {
               "Date": "Date(2014,5,2)",
               "Users":103
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "Jerry",
         "UsersByDate": [
            {
               "Date": "Date(2014,5,1)",
               "Users": 63
            },
            {
               "Date": "Date(2014,5,2)",
               "Users": 24
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
    }
```

The issue might relate to the Date format I'm using. I've tried getting rid of the 'new' keyword along with storing the dates in different formats (such as UTC), but I've read that the current format "Date(YYYY,MM,DD)" is what Google Charts accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have several mistakes. Firstly, you are missing a ] in your json. Also, change this part:

```
          $.each(data.UsersByDateList, function (key, value) {
              $.each(value.UsersByDate, function (key2, value2) {
                  var item = [value2.Date, value.Name, value2.Users];
                  array.push(item);
              });
          });
```

Still need to fix the date, but this should get rid of errors on the drawing of the chart

Update: The part you had in comment worked, you just needeed to include jquery. Still, you had a big issue with your date format, because the way you had it only works if you set in json format the chart in the dataTable. Also, always try to avoid using eval. You can check the fix I made here:

http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/xhp3g7u9/1/

Comment: Whoops. I copied this part of the JSON from a much larger file and forgot to include the last ]. Also, changing element.UsersByDate to value.UsersByDate (the change you made) was just a copy and past error. Neither of these fixes, unfortunately, print the data to the table.

Comment: By the way, the chart draws just fine, and shows the 2 sample elements as expected.

Comment: @4815162342 so what's the problem then? The date? Maybe you could make a jsfiddle with your sample data

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4815162342/xhp3g7u9/

The commented out part in the middle is what needs work. I can't get that data added to the table. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.